# Canonical correlation analysis with ade4

Tags: r, statistics

Was the cca function deprecated in R's ade4 package?

```
library(ade4)
cca(mammals, environment)
```

outputs

```
could not find function "cca"
```

I can't find any documentation on this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `cca` function in `ade4` package version 1.7-10. However, you can use `cancor` from base `R` like below

```
pop <- LifeCycleSavings[, 2:3]
oec <- LifeCycleSavings[, -(2:3)]
cancor(pop, oec)
```

**Edited**

Install version 1.7-4 using the following code

```
library(devtools)
install_version("ade4", version = "1.7-4", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

and then run

```
library(ade4)
```

Comment: It was implemented at some point though: https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/ade4/ade4-html/cca.html

Comment: The latest version of `ade4` is 1.7-10.  However version 1.7-4 has `cca` function.

Comment: Thanks, I tested different versions and 1.7-6 is the latest that still has it.

Answer (score 0):

May be is not available for the newest versions of the package. Nevertheless it is suggested to use `cca{vegan}`, which is form the `vegan` library.